# For a recursive call without a base condition, why does the compiler not show an error during compilation?

Tags: c++

I have been programming using the C++ language for quite some time now. I recently came across a situation for which I need help. For a recursive call without a base condition, why does the compiler not show an error during compilation? I, however, receive an error message during runtime.

Take the following for an example. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int fibonacci(int n){
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

int main(){
    int ans = fibonacci(6);
    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Speaking plainly, the code is valid and compilable. It will just run "forever" (until resources are exhausted).

Comment: @Rogue The code is not correct, it will always lead to an underflow, which is UB for `int`. Additionally, an infinite loop with no side effects or forward progression is also UB, and not allowed. `while(true);` is not allowed in C++.

Comment: *why does the compiler not show an error during compilation?*  In general, C++ compilers are not required to detect that a program is ill-formed.  There are a few situations that a C++ compiler is required to detect and report that a program is ill-formed; this scenario is not one of those few cases.  (Some compilers provide additional lint-like warnings based on static analysis, but that's above-and-beyond from the standard.)

Comment: what compiler are you using? warnings enabled?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The term "underflow" is used in floating-point calculations where you get a result that falls into the gap between the smallest-magnitude representable non-zero numbers.  You're right that subtracting 1 from INT_MIN is UB, but it's technically an "overflow issue", even though it's at the left end of the representable number line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern compilers, in their quest to help you out and generate near-optimal code, will indeed recognize that this function never terminates.  However, nothing in the C or C++ language specifications requires that.  In contrast to languages like Prolog or Haskell, C/C++ do not guarantee any semantic analysis of your program.  A very simple compiler would turn your code

```
int fibonacci(int n){
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

into a sequence of low-level instructions equivalent to

- set a = n - 1
- set b = n - 2
- put a in the stack position or register for the first int argument
- call function fibonacci
- move the return value into temporary x
- put b in the stack position or register for the first int argument
- call function fibonacci
- move the return value into temporary y
- set z = x + y
- move z into the stack position or register for the function return value
- return to caller

This is a perfectly legal compilation of your program, and does not require any errors or warnings to be generated.  Obviously, during execution, the "move the return value into temporary x" and later instructions (most significantly, the "return to caller") will never be reached.  This will generate an infinite recursion loop until the machine stack space is exhausted.

Answer (score 5):

The premise of the question is false. [GCC reports](https://godbolt.org/z/1MEj3zW4e):

```
: In function 'int fibonacci(int)':
:6:5: warning: infinite recursion detected [-Winfinite-recursion]
    6 | int fibonacci(int n){
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
:8:21: note: recursive call
    8 |     return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

[Clang reports](https://godbolt.org/z/nbvf88sfx):

```
:6:21: warning: all paths through this function will call itself [-Winfinite-recursion]
int fibonacci(int n){
                    ^
1 warning generated.
```

[MSVC reports](https://godbolt.org/z/9xKc644aa):

```
(9) : warning C4717: 'fibonacci': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
```

Comment: The premise is not necessarily false, unless the language requires a diagnostic. As far as I know, a compiler is allowed to not detect or warn the user of this problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: The premise is “the compiler not show an error during compilation.” Compilers, at least some of them, do show a diagnostic (which may be elevated to an error with the appropriate switch). Therefore, the premise that “the” compiler does not show a diagnostic is false. If the question were restated as “Why does the C++ standard not require a diagnostic?”, that would be a different question.

Comment: You're assuming specific compilers or compilation flags. It very well may be that they do not see this message when they compile this code. "The compiler" here implies "the compiler I am using".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yes, it may be that **a** compiler does not show this message. That is not what the question says.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is exactly what the question is asking. Until they provide which compiler they are using, "the compiler" means the abstract concept of a generic C++ compiler. Stating that the premise is false means that you are telling them that, in fact, their compiler did show them a diagnostic. You don't know that this is accurate, and the question itself implies that it is not. This answer would be fine if it was formatted to instead show how to enable these warnings for popular compilers, showing that most compiler actually do have the ability to diagnose this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: OP is free to clarify the question if they wish. Meanwhile, an unqualified “the compiler” is a general statement, and that general statement is false.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, you are absolutely right. By the term "compiler", I meant the abstract concept of a generic C++ compiler